# How to pad a message sent using C# sockets with null values?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I have an application (whose logic is abstracted from me, but I am trying to replicate) that is sending data via TCP/IP to a remote socket. Inspecting the data on Wireshark shows the below output:

```
0000   fc 73 fb c7 cb 21 f8 e4 3b aa 27 c2 08 00 45 00   .s...!..;.'...E.
0010   00 64 df 77 40 00 80 06 00 00 0a 01 10 a2 0a e9   .d.w@...........
0020   eb 96 f2 2d 1b b8 03 e4 9b 15 73 2c 73 9c 50 18   ...-......s,s.P.
0030   04 00 11 79 00 00 00 00 00 38                     ...y.....8
```

When I hover over the output in Wireshark, I can see it groups
`00 00 00 38` towards the end and describes it as `Data(data.data)`.

I have tried to emulate this using the below C# code:

```cs
try
{
    IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
    IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new(ip, 7096);
    using Socket client = new Socket(ipEndPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    await client.ConnectAsync(ipEndPoint);
    // Send message.
    var message = "8";
    var messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
    client.SendTimeout = 10000;
    client.ReceiveTimeout = 10000;
    _ = await client.SendAsync(messageBytes, SocketFlags.None);
    client.Send(messageBytes, SocketFlags.None);

    Console.WriteLine($"Socket client sent message: \"{message}\"");

    // Receive ack.
    var buffer = new byte[1_024];
    var received = client.Receive(buffer, SocketFlags.None);
    var response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, received);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Socket client received acknowledgment: \"{response}\"");

    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Response is empty");
    }

    client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

And my output on Wireshark is:

```
0000   fc 73 fb c7 cb 21 f8 e4 3b aa 27 c2 08 00 45 00   .s...!..;.'...E.
0010   00 29 e0 2a 40 00 80 06 00 00 0a 01 10 a2 0a e9   .).*@...........
0020   eb 96 f6 f5 1b b8 0d 0f 64 de 09 30 2b 29 50 18   ........d..0+)P.
0030   04 00 11 3e 00 00 38                              ...>..8
```

When I hover over this output in Wireshark, it groups
`38` and describes it as `Data(data.data)`.

I am trying to figure out how to get that extra `00 00 00` to appear in my output before the `38`. I believe this extra detail is necessary for my remote host to understand the message I am trying to push to it.

I did some research and found out that `00` in hex translates to `NUL` in ASCII, and I don't know how I would add that to my message in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string `"8"` encoded in UTF-8 is a single byte `0x38`, which is what you are sending (*twice*, I might add).  That is why Wireshark is grouping it by itself.

However, the byte sequence `00 00 00 38` does not represent a `"8"` UTF-8 string at all. It actually represents a 4-byte integer `56` in big endian format (ie, network byte order). That is what you should be sending instead, eg:

```cs
/*
var message = "8";
var messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
*/
int message = 56;
var messageBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(message);
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    Array.Reverse(messageBytes);
```

Alternatively:

```
int message = 56;
var messageBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(message));
```

Alternatively:

```
int message = 56;
var messageBytes = new byte[4];
messageBytes[0] = (byte)(message >> 24);
messageBytes[1] = (byte)(message >> 16);
messageBytes[2] = (byte)(message >> 8);
messageBytes[3] = (byte)message;
```

Comment: i used the second option and it works as expected. Turns out the abstracted application would get the total length of the message being sent, turn it into this big endian format you mentioned, pad the message at the front with this length and send it to the remot ip. So 56 here was actually the length of the message that i truncated in my original question since i didn't know it was necessary. I used this code ```byte[] finalMessageBytes = messageLenghtBytes.Concat(messageBytes).ToArray();``` to get the final set of bytes to send to the remote IP.

Comment: "*I used this code ... to get the final set of bytes to send to the remote IP*' - You don't need to do that. You can just send the length bytes by themselves following by the message bytes by themselves, eg: `var message = ...; var messageBytes = ...; int messageLength = messageBytes.Length; var messageLengthBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(messageLength)); Send(messageLengthBytes); Send(messageBytes);` TCP is a stream, you don't have to send everything all at once.